# find image src that :contains?

Tags: jquery, contains, src

Morning all,

I have a list of images like so:

```
<ul id="preload" style="display:none;">
<li><img src="afx4000z-navy-icon-1_thumb.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="afx4000z-green-icon-1_thumb.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery how find all image src's within ul#preload that contain a specific string eg."green"

something like...

```
var new_src = jQuery('#preload img').attr('src')*** that contains green ***;
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to use [the `*=` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
jQuery('#preload img[src*="green"]')
```

If you want it to be case insensitive, it will be a bit more difficult:

```
var keyword = "green";
$("#preload img").filter(function(keyword) {
    return $(this).attr("src").toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});
```

Comment: Your second example would throw an error, numbers have no method `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: How can I use this logic to find all the images that dont have green in them?

Comment: I believe `function(keyword)` there is misleading and semantically wrong. one option to fix it is simply changing it to `function()`. am I right, though? :P

Answer (score 10):

You can use an [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (`[attr*=value]`), like this:

```
jQuery('#preload img[src*=green]')
```

Comment: wrong. `green` should be in quotes. From the link: "Quotes are mandatory."

Comment: lovely, is it case sensitive? guess it would be... how can I use it not to be case sensitive?

Comment: @Gabi - they aren't required, test it yourself...they're only needed if the value contains any special characters.