# jQuery: How to find element with same src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two separate `div` elements, each containing `img` elements.

```
<div>
    <img class="circle" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="three.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="four.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="six.jpg"/>
</div>
```

In this example, one set of `img` elements has the same `src` value.

If I click on `<img class="circle" src="one.jpg"/>` in the first `div`, what is the best way to find the `img` with `class="square"` containing the same `src` value using jQuery?

Comment: You should show what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: `$("img[src='one.jpg']");` read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498177/find-image-src-that-contains

Comment: Usually, a great idea to try SOMETHING and come back with a "Hey, this didn't work and I don't know why." Otherwise, this begins to feel like doing someone's homework FOR them.

Comment: That's understandable. I really just didn't know what to try. There are a lot of people that come on here because they're very new to this and don't know what they're doing (like myself). I will keep that in mind for future posts, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what the source is of the clicked element and then build a selector that goes and selects images of the same source.

```js
$("img").click(function(){
  // Grab the source from the clicked element
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  // Select other elements with the same source and do something with it.
  $("img[src='"+src+"']").css("border", "1px solid red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img class="circle" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="three.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="four.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="six.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvote for commenting your code. This week, that's my major mantra. Nicely done.

Comment: Definitely agree on the code commenting. I'm trying to do this as much as possible now.

Answer (score 2):

Use attr selector combined with the class, and make sure they have the same src otherwise you should validate if the src exists...

```js
$('.circle').click(function(){
  var src=$(this).attr('src').trim();
  var squareImage = $('.square[src="'+src+'"]');
  console.log(squareImage); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img class="circle" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="three.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="three.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to highlight the images in all sibling divs, rather than also highlighting the clicked image, here you go.

```js
$("img").on("click", function(){
  // First, remove the highlight from ALL images
  $("img").removeClass("foo");
  // Next, in all sibling divs to this img's
  //  parent div, find any with a matching src.
  //  For those that match, add the highlight.
  $(this).parent().siblings().find("[src='"+$(this).attr("src")+"']").addClass("foo");
  
  });
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.foo{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-pane">
<div>
    <img class="circle" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="three.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="four.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="six.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```